# Resizing shapess within shapes in Visio using C#

Tags: c#, .net, interop, visio

So I am using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio` Class Library and I am trying to write C# to automate the creation of topology diagrams. This particular topology diagram needs to have three different network zones and depending on the purpose of the server, it will go into the proper network zone. The network zones are shapes themselves, as well as shapes for the servers.

My challenge is that when the program is fed a data file that specifies the type of servers needed, I need to make sure that the servers are put into the right zones and that the zone is resized to fit the shapes properly.

I am at a point where I can successfully add the server shapes to a new diagram and have them connect to each other using the Shape.Autoconnect method. However, I am stuck on figuring out how I am supposed to accomplish what I described above.

Any thoughts/guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Adding shapes to new diagram

```
Master visioConnectorShapeHttps = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"HTTPS Line");
Master visioConnectorShapeSQL = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"SQLConnection");

Master visioWebRoleMaster = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Azure PaaS WebRole Tier");
Shape visioWebRoleShape = visioPage.Drop(visioWebRoleMaster, 10, 16);

Master visioWorkerRoleMaster = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Azure PaaS WorkerRole Tier");
Shape visioWorkerRoleShape = visioPage.Drop(visioWorkerRoleMaster, 10, 10);

visioWebRoleShape.AutoConnect(visioWorkerRoleShape, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirDown, visioConnectorShapeHttps);

Master visioSQLIaaSMaster = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Azure IaaS Database Tier");
Shape visioSQLIaaSShape = visioPage.Drop(visioSQLIaaSMaster, 10, 3);

visioWorkerRoleShape.AutoConnect(visioSQLIaaSShape, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirDown, visioConnectorShapeSQL);
```

I would like to programmatically feed the app a data file and automate the creation of a topology diagram where server shapes properly fit into various proper network zone shapes.

Comment: Pedantic, maybe, but a small correction to your terminology ... in your text (not the code) where you have "stencil", change it to "shape". A stencil in Visio terminology is a file containing master shapes. So, you are not encompassing stencils within stencils. You could be dropping shapes within containers or within group shapes ...

Comment: @PaulHerber - Done. Any thoughts on resizing shapes to fit more shapes?